# Папка .vs весит слишком много Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

На сколько я знаю, папка ".vs" предназначена для хранения пользовательских настроек проэкта.
Раньше, на Visual Studio 2015 такая папка весила до 10мб, но стоило мне обновится до 2017 вижуалки и объем папки (в том же самом проекте) стал занимать более 400 мб. И так во всех других проектах. Даже если создать полностью чистый проэкт, то папка .vs уже весит до 20 мб.

Вопрос состоит в следующем:
Если это баг, то как исправить?
Если это не баг, то существует ли возможность настроить объем данной папки?

Comment: Не наблюдаю такого. У меня в большинстве проектов она даже до 1МБ не дотягивает, самый большой размер - 1,3 МБ. Что у вас в ней лежит?

Comment: Вот ссылка на почти пустой проект:
http://github.com/MihailYa/Rubish

На сколько я понял, размер проекта на прямую зависит от того сколько я добавил файлов в precomilled header (stdafx.h)
Я добавил в stdafx.h
`#include <fstream>`
И размер файла .vs увеличился на 20Мб
Но почему в 2015 вижуалке это почти не влияло на размер данной папки?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У вас в папке .vs складируется база intellisense. Это можно отключить выставив в настройках студии на вкладке `Text Editor` -> `C/C++` -> `Advanced` -> `Fallback Location` опцию `Always use Fallback Location` на True и опцию `Do not Warn If Fallback Location Used` на `True`. В этой группе еще есть третья опция, позволяющая задавать конкретное расположение для этих данных (по-умолчанию они попадают в temp кажется). После этого следует закрыть студию (все) и удалить папку `.vs`. При следующем запуске студия заново создаст базу для intellisense в новом расположении, а в папке `.vs` будет только маленький файл `.suo`. Кроме того, при добавлении в репозиторий папку `.vs` следует исключать в любом случае.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое, только что проект стал легче на 2 Gb! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Папка .vs не только для пользовательских настроек, а вообще для складирования всяких вспомогательных данных. Как минимум там кэшируется индекс IntelliSens`a. В предыдущих версиях студия создавала, для своих нужд, в папке с решением отдельные файлы, теперь видимо это все решили в отдельную папку свалить чтобы было меньше бардака.

Явной специальной настройки объема папки .vs в студии нет. Навряд ли это ошибка.