# Как сделать меньше папку решения в версии VC 17.2.1 (Windows 10)

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Подскажите пожалуйста как настроить Visual Studio 17 чтоб размер папки решения уменьшить. Например при создании простого консольного проекта папка решения составляет 86,7 МБ.

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{ 
  std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

Comment: У меня ощущение, что разве что компилировать без среды, в командной строке :)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/743757/%d0%9f%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b0-vs-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%88%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-visual-studio-2017/743966#743966